# How do I disable the close button in my goog.ui.Dialog?

Tags: google-closure-library

I would like to get rid of the close/X button on the top right corner of my Google Closure dialog.

I am browsing the documentation (http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_ui_Dialog.html) and cannot find the method to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`goog.ui.Dialog`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_ui_Dialog.html) title-bar close button can be disabled by first calling [`goog.ui.Dialog.prototype.getTitleCloseElement()`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_ui_dialog.js.source.html#line337) followed by [`goog.style.showElement(el, display)`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_style_style.js.source.html#line1059).

**Example**

```js
var dialog = new goog.ui.Dialog();
dialog.setContent('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer' +
    'adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin ultrices urna. Proin vehicula ' +
    'mauris ac est. Ut scelerisque, risus ut facilisis dictum, est massa ' +
    'lacinia lorem, in fermentum purus ligula quis nunc. Duis porttitor ' +
    'euismod risus. Nam hendrerit lacus vehicula augue. Duis ante.');
dialog.setTitle('Lorem ipsum');
dialog.setButtonSet(goog.ui.Dialog.ButtonSet.createYesNo());

var titleCloseEl = dialog.getTitleCloseElement();
goog.style.showElement(titleCloseEl, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

The method is there! See http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_Dialog.html

```
dialog.setHasTitleCloseButton(false);
```

Regards,

Rene